# How to set response code while using json views with Grails 3

Tags: json, grails, http-status-codes

I am now in process of switching to use json view in one of my apps built with Grails 3.3

It all looks pretty simple and here is one of my controllers:

```
def create(ProjectCommand command) {
        if (command.validate()) {
            // do something with user
            Project project = projectService.create(command, springSecurityService.principal.id as Long)

            if (project) {
                [status: HttpStatus.CREATED, project: project]
            } else {
                badRequest("failed to create the project")
            }
        }
        else {
            badRequest(command.errors)
        }
    }
```

Here, I assumed that the status will be used as a response status code, but it does not.
Is there an easy way to set status code of the response without explicitly going through `render`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... that was easy.
Apparently, inside the view file itself, there is a way to almost anything.
For this particular case, it is enough to do:

```
response.status HttpStatus.CREATED
```

I hope it will be useful to someone